Partitions for Delta Lake External Tables in Snowflake
i am trying to create partitions for External Tables of type Delta Lake. Unfortunately the Delta Lake file system does not have a partition implemented neither, which means no partition is mentioned in metadata. Also the file name does not contain date or any other indicator to implement partition.
So i tried implementing my own partition based on last modified data metadata
metadata$file_last_modified
But then Snowflake is throwing an error when i do so.
Defining expression for partition column part1 is invalid.
Here is my table definition
create or replace external table  DPA_PCLOG_TEST(
    file_name STRING as metadata$filename,
    **part1 DATE as DATE(metadata$file_last_modified),**
    part2 CHAR(5) as SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(metadata$filename, '/', 3),'-',2),
    part3 timestamp_tz as (parse_json(metadata$external_table_partition):local_log_time::timestamp_tz),
    application_id NUMBER  AS  (VALUE:application_id::NUMBER) ,
    computer_id NUMBER  AS  (VALUE:computer_id::NUMBER) ,
    duration NUMBER  AS  (VALUE:duration::NUMBER) ,
    employee_id NUMBER  AS  (VALUE:employee_id::NUMBER) ,
    id NUMBER  AS  (VALUE:id::NUMBER) ,
    key_presses NUMBER  AS  (VALUE:key_presses::NUMBER) ,
    local_log_time TIMESTAMP  AS  (VALUE:local_log_time::TIMESTAMP) ,
    log_time TIMESTAMP  AS  (VALUE:log_time::TIMESTAMP) ,
    mouse_clicks NUMBER  AS  (VALUE:mouse_clicks::NUMBER) ,
    productivity BOOLEAN  AS  (VALUE:productivity::BOOLEAN) ,
    tenantid NUMBER  AS  (VALUE:tenantid::NUMBER) ,
    updated_time TIMESTAMP  AS  (VALUE:updated_time::TIMESTAMP) ,
    url STRING  AS  (VALUE:url::STRING) ,
    url_domain STRING  AS  (VALUE:url_domain::STRING) ,
    web_page BOOLEAN  AS  (VALUE:web_page::BOOLEAN) ,
    window_title STRING  AS  (VALUE:window_title::STRING) ,
    year_week  NUMBER  AS  (VALUE:year_week::NUMBER) 
)
partition by (part1)
with location = @VERINT_EDH_STAGE/Verint/dpa_pclog/ 
refresh_on_create = false 
auto_refresh = false 
file_format = (type = parquet) 
table_format = delta
;

Is there anyway i can implement this partition without errors ?

per the documentation, A partition column must evaluate as an expression that parses the path and/or filename information in the METADATA$FILENAME pseudocolumn.  You are attempting to use a different metadata function that is not supported.

I should also point out that partitioning is primarily useful for limiting the amount of data being updated underneath the external table, rather than performance on queries against the external tables.  If you are concerned with query performance, I'd recommend a materialized view over the external table that has an auto-cluster specified.
